# Can I alter the "Execute Procedure" pop up window in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, user-interface, ssms

My boss would like to see an example of the data type when executing stored procedures.

When you execute a stored procedure, a popup window appears showing parameter,data type, output parameter, pass null value and value. For example, if the parameter and data type is a date he wants to be able to visually see on that screen what format the date should be entered "YYYY-MM-DD", "YYYY-DD-MM", etc.

If the parameter was customer name and the data type is `nvarchar(128)` he wants to know what that would look like. Ideally, I would like to insert a new column on this popup that shows an example of the intended format. I'm just not sure if it's possible.

I've searched on google and stack overflow for SQL user interface changes, SQL 
formatting tools and altering stored procedures. So far I've seen are articles from Microsoft on Graphical Query Designer User Interfaces, Apex SQL Refractor, and posts on this site that are not quite what I'm looking for.

I'm not sure my boss would want me to share my company's code online.

I've only been working with SQL for a few months so I'm not super familiar with how to alter things, only how to query and organize the results so any help would be appreciated. Below is what the popup window looks like currently.

[image]

Comment: This sounds like your boss shouldn't be using SSMS and should be using an application layer that provides examples, and also doesn't allow them to input incorrect values (like providing a date picker for dates, and not allowing alphas for a numerical field). If they *must* use SSMS for some unknown and probably silly reasonm then they need to learn (at least the basics of) SQL. SSMS is an IDE, it's not a user interface for people that have no idea what they're doing (like your boss). *Also, using the GUI to execute SPs? Really? I would at least recommend using an `EXEC` statement.*

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for steering me in the right direction. Do you have any recommendations for application layers that provide examples? If we can't change, I'll probably make a quick and easy instruction manual for the company.

Comment: *"Do you have any recommendations for application layers that provide examples?"* SO isn't a website for asking for recommendations, however, I was suggesting you build your own application layer.

Comment: Oh, I apologize. I'm new to all of this, I didn't know. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You might want to check out Azure Data Studio https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Orv7fptVoUA which doesn't do what you want, but has a lot of boss friendly stuff like addins and charts and stuff. You might be able to find an addin that does what you want. Or you could write it yourself. At least you have the option

Comment: Also just keep in mind... there's not necessarily an easy way to define valid values for stored proc parameters. You'd basically have to hard code it